# Can we move selection item to second position in wheel in android.

Tags: android

[image]

Can we change selection item to second instead of center of item wheel as it is in image.

Comment: what library are you using

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am trying to explore example in github example. link is https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel. Can you please help me to move selection item to second item.